# onHover event is not triggering in chart.js

Tags: jquery, cursor, chart.js, onhover

I want to change the cursor when the mouse moves on the chart, something like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/su5fgb5h/5/).
This works with chart.js `v2.4` but not works  with `v2.6` & `v2.7`
any idea?

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");
 var mychart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
  labels: ['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro'],
   datasets: [{
  data: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  backgroundColor: ["#BDC3C7","#9B59B6","#E74C3C","#26B99A"]
   }]
    },
    options: {
    hover: {
  onHover: function(e) {
    $("#canvas1").css("cursor", e[0] ? "pointer" : "default");

    /* without jquery it can be like this:
      var el = document.getElementById("canvas1");
      el.style.cursor = e[0] ? "pointer" : "default";
    */
  }
 }
 }
  });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `v2.5` onwards parameters of onHover callback has been changed. See [PR#3669](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/3669)

> onHover callback now has 3 parameters. The 2nd parameter is the event
>   that triggered the hover. This was done for consistency with the
>   onClick callback.

```
function(event, activeElements) {

}
```

Previously, activeEvents was the first argument, and event was not passed.

You can check [release notes of v2.5](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v2.5.0)

So you've to change your `onHover callback` as follows:

```
  onHover: function(event,elements) {
    $("#canvas1").css("cursor", elements[0] ? "pointer" : "default");
  }
```

[updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prashantpokhriyal/77jLzx8a)

Comment: Is there any event which remove onHover event on remove the hover.